# Updating PHP version Plesk 12.0.18 VPS

Tags: php, plesk

I have a VPS with 1&1, running Plesk 12.0.18. My current PHP version is showing as 5.3.3 and even though I've installed (I think) newer PHP versions in the 'Install/Update Components' section of the panel the PHP version doesn't seem to change and I can't change the version.

I'm trying to install the new version of Magento to one of my sites and it won't install without at least PHP 5.4.

Can anyone please help? Is there a place within the panel where I can simply 'switch on' the newer version of PHP? My knowledge of servers is limited so I'm not 100% comfortable in SSH.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Note that newest PHP packages from the Plesk team are available on CentOS 6, CentOS 7, and Ubuntu 14 only. If you have other OS - you can't install these PHP versions. Anyway try to do it in CLI with

plesk sbin autoinstaller --select-product-id plesk --select-release-current  --install-component php5.6

Also make sure that you have installed all latest Plesk microupdates (MU#60 is last).

Comment: you should also tell where to run these commands to update php version

Answer (score 0):

php is linked to your old php version.
You can i.e. change the php alias to your new php version.

Check this, which helped for me:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163762/php-cli-and-bash-change-behaviour-of-php-keyword